# Requisição AJAX para página PHP não está sendo enviada

Tags: php, ajax

Boa noite ,

Pessoal,minha página 'l_os' lista e altera todos os itens em outra pagina corretamente.Só que estou alterando todas as páginas para que exiba e altere através de uma única página á index.Ai que entra o ajax , em minha index eu apresento a página que lista todos os itens que ao clicar na ação alterar o ajax chama a página que altera e apresenta os valores nos campos.O problema esta quando clico no alterar o valor esta indo errado para o ajax apresentando outro valor nos campos é somente a primeira linha que consigo clicar as demais não acontece nada.

Desde que coloquei os parâmetros no ajax para poder recuperar os valores na pagina que altera, não esta funcionando corretamente , creio eu que o ajax esta pegando somente uma linha da minha lista independente em qual linha da tabela eu clico para alterar.

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeceria muito.

Página 'l_os'

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Cadastro Funcionario</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="style/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="style/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>

<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="page-header">
         <h3>Consulta Ordem de Serviço</h3> 
       </div>
       <div class="">
             <a href="#" id="cadastro_os" class="btn btn-default btn-cadastrar-btn">Incluir OS</a>
       </div>
       <table style="width: 450px" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive " >

         <thead >
           <th> Prótocolo</th>          
           <th> Funcionario</th> 
           <th>  Cliente</th> 
           <th>  Email</th> 
           <th>  Telefone</th> 
           <th>  Celular</th> 
           <th>  CPF</th> 
           <th>  Cidade</th> 
           <th> Endereço</th> 
           <th> Serviço</th> 
           <th>  Situacao</th> 
           <th>  Data_OS</th> 
           <th colspan="2"> Ações</th> 
         </thead>

         <tbody >
           <?php

           $CODAO = new OsDAO();
           $query = $CODAO->listar_os();
          foreach($query as $reg):  
           ?>

          <tr class="success largura">
          <td> <?=$reg["id_protocolo"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["nome_funcionario"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["nome"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["email"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["telefone"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["telefone_celular"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["cpf"] ?></td>
          <td> <?=$reg["cidade"] ?></td>
          <td > <?=$reg["endereco"] ?></td>
          <td > <?=$reg["nome_servico"] ?></td>
          <td > <?=$reg["situacao"] ?></td>
          <td > <?=date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($reg["data_os"])); ?></td>

          <td >
             <center>
                //id para o ajax ativar a função clicar
             <a id="alterar_os" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Alterar</a>
             </center>

           </td>
          </tr>


        </tbody>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cadastro_os').click(function(){//essa parte do ajax funciona perfeito para incluir
           $( "#cliente1" ).load( "os/c_os.php" );
        });
        $('#alterar_os').click(function(){
           $( "#cliente1" ).load( "os/a_os.php?IDCLI=<?=$reg["id_cliente"];?>&IDFUN=<?=$reg["id_funcionario"];?>&IDSER=<?=$reg["id_servico"];?>&IDOS=<?=$reg["id_protocolo"];?>" );
        });

   });
    </script>
      <?php   
      endforeach;
      ?>
      </table>

</div>
</body>


<script src="style/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não dá mesmo. Tente usar um script pra envio da requisição. Depois puxe pelo ajax. Dá um número a cada campo que for carregar. E passe pelo onclick o número da linha que irá puxar os campos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Existem duas *tags* `<head>` no código, exclua uma.

**2.** Você está finalizando a instrução `foreach` do PHP no lugar errado. Você deve finalizá-la logo que você conclui a linha da tabela, indicada pela *tag* `</tr>`.

```
<table style="width: 450px" class="..." >
  <thead >
    <th>Protocolo</th>          
    <th>Funcionario</th> 
    <th>Cliente</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Telefone</th> 
    <th>Celular</th> 
    <th>CPF</th> 
    <th>Cidade</th> 
    <th>Endereço</th> 
    <th>Serviço</th> 
    <th>Situacao</th> 
    <th>Data_OS</th> 
    <th colspan="2">Ações</th> 
  </thead>

  <tbody >
    <?php
      $CODAO = new OsDAO();
      $query = $CODAO->listar_os();

      foreach($query as $reg):
    ?>
    <tr class="success largura">
      <td><?= $reg["id_protocolo"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["nome_funcionario"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["nome"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["email"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["telefone"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["telefone_celular"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["cpf"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["cidade"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["endereco"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["nome_servico"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $reg["situacao"]; ?></td>
      <td><?= date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($reg["data_os"])); ?></td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <a id="alterar_os" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Alterar</a>
        </center>    
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
```

**3.** Pelo seu código JavaScript, para editar o registro, você precisa dos valores de `id_cliente`, `id_funcionario`, `id_servico` e `id_protocolo`. Esses dados precisamos obter dentro do nosso laço PHP e associar, de alguma forma, ao *link* Alterar. Para isso, podemos armazenar a URL em um atributo extra, que chamarei de `data-url`.

```
<a href="#" data-url="os/a_os.php?IDCLI=<?=$reg["id_cliente"];?>&IDFUN=<?=$reg["id_funcionario"];?>&IDSER=<?=$reg["id_servico"];?>&IDOS=<?=$reg["id_protocolo"];?>" class="btn btn-default alterar_os">Alterar</a>
```

> Perceba que alterei o *id* da *tag* `a` pela *class* `alterar_os`. Fazer isso é necessário porque o atributo *id* deve ser único na página. Como haverá múltiplos registros, é necessário posicionar o identificador para a *class*.

**4.** Agora, no JavaScript, para fazer a requisição AJAX, basta retomar o valor do atributo `data-url` do elemento pressionado e fazer a requisição sobre ela.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $('.alterar_os').click(function(){
      $("#cliente1").load($(this).attr("data-url"));
    });
  });
```

> Perceba também que como foi alterado do *id* para *class* o identificador dos links, no jQuery, o seletor passou de `#alterar_os` para `.alterar_os`.

Só não sei onde o elemento `#cliente1`, no qual será carregado o conteúdo, fica na sua página HTML.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson.Pela sua resposta você entendeu perfeitamente minha duvida.O elemento #cliente1 é onde vai ser carregado a pagina 'l_os'  na' index'.Esta maneira de criar um atributo e atribuir o caminho com os valores vai me ajudar muito em outros casos.Resolveu perfeitamente meu problema